# How do I deploy react native iOS app to app store with fast lane on windows?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, xcode9, fastlane

I'm using windows 10 and I want to know that how do I able to deploy an ios app to app store created using react native and fast lane.
Some people's on internet said we can use app loader instead of xcode to deploy app on ios app store. Is it possible?
In short: do let me know the way to deploy react native based ios app to app store using windows pc?
P.S. I don't want hackintosh or VMware.

Comment: Please! I have no knowledge about deployment I just completed react native and built an prototype Android app now I wanna do same for ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create an iOS build from non mac machine , ur best bet is using app-center

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/ios/

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. You will need a Mac with Xcode installed to build and upload react native apps for iOS.

Comment: That also runs on a Mac, but you'd still need to compile for iOS first, using Xcode's tools.

Comment: Okay so Xcode is necessary. But app loader is also running 9n windows I just downloaded from the official website and installed it on windows machine
Check url http://appuploader.net/appuploader/download.php

Comment: Whatever that tool is, it's certainly not the official App Uploader from Apple. "Application Loader" comes bundled with Xcode.